# Initialise angularjs after ajax

Tags: ajax, angularjs

*Hello*, how to initialise AngularJS app after AJAX ?
AJAX is separate from AngularJS, so i have bugs with it, it doesn't display the values.
**What to do ?**

Answer (score 0):

You will need to trigger Angular's digest cycle with a call to [$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply).

Alternatively, you can use the built-in services to get data over AJAX, [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) or [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). They'll take care of initiating the digest cycle when data arrives.

Comment: the problem is that i can't use the built-in service , because it's separate from angularjs. any solutions please ?)

Comment: If the component making the AJAX call offers a callback when the data is received, you can call $apply then. Are you initiating the request from an Angular controller or service? If so inject `$rootScope` and call `$rootScope.$apply()` at the end of the callback.

Comment: Can you give me more details about it please(how to use it and where please ), the problem is that the variables are unreadable , in other words it displays the brackets. Thank you. but just more details please ). the request from a controller.

Comment: I would need more info. Code snippets around the AJAX request would be a good start.

Comment: well it's big project , so you know ... , so basically to initialise the angularjs after ajax , ajax is absolutely separate, i have to use $rootScope.$apply() at the end of the controller , right ?

Comment: You would use `$rootScope.$apply()` at the end of the AJAX call's success callback, assuming there is one.

Comment: But the controller contains no ajax.